# cPanel & WHM - cPanel - Email - Email Filters - File Location?

Tags: email, cpanel, filtering

So what I am doing is managing several dozen email accounts on the back end putting filters on the accounts to keep some "persistent you really did sign up for our newsletters but you can't unsubscribe" type emails to be just plain "be gone you vermin" status.

And a few redirects due to the sender sending the email to the wrong inbox type of stuff.

But been trying to locate both the global filters and the per email account filters and am having trouble searching the internet for where they are. Specifically I'd like to be able to download them, parse them, and produce a worksheet of what which ones does what to whom and why.

So anyone familiar with cPanel can help me with this?